# Want to color values in td on condition using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to color negative values to red based on condition, I am doing like this now:

```
$('td.numeric:contains('-')").addClass("negative")
```

above code find td which have class name numeric and if value contains '-', it applies class 'negative' to that td.

My problem is that, if I apply numeric class to for example date values which also contains '-' as separator and makes date to color red.

So my question is that How can I find td with values startwith '-'?

like

```
$('td.numeric:startwith('-')").addClass("negative")
```

CSS

```
.numeric {  text-align:right; }
.negative { text-align:right; color:red; }
```

Comment: This solves your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824266/colorize-negative-positive-numbers-jquery

Comment: is there any inbuilt function for startwith without regex?

Comment: can't you put a class on the date td's and simply exclude them using `.not()`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("td.numeric").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).indexOf("-") == 0;
}).addClass("negative")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("td").each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
if (/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/.test(text)) {
 var num = parseFloat(text);
 if (num < 0) {
   $(this).addClass("negative"); //add negative class
 } else if (num > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("positive"); //add positive class
 }

 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it this way:

```
$('td.numeric').filter(function(){return this.innerHTML[0] === '-';});
```

or safer as:

```
$('td.numeric').filter(function(){return this.innerHTML.match(/^\s*-/;});
```

put a lot of functions inside jquery selector only hurts the performance, using filters is better choice.